# How do I get back to X?

Tags: gnome, terminal

I pressed some key combination and got a big full screen black terminal screen with a login prompt.
After logging in, I tried [startx](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=launch%20gnome%20from%20commandline#hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=NO6bTZDIJOHP4wbBtpGCBw&ved=0CBIQBSgA&q=launch%20gnome%20from%20command%20line&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=ae3fa2fab1e0dd34) to get the UI back, but got a message

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock and start again.
```

So - what did I do to get me the black prompt in the first place, and how do I get back to X?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> for some `n`, and you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (usually) to get back.

Comment: You mean Ctrl+Alt+F7?

Comment: @Michael: The text mode console usually wants `Alt`; X11 uses `Ctrl`+`Alt` because of programs that used `Alt` + F-keys (WordPerfect for Unix, back when, did that a lot).

Comment: Wow, you're right; I've always used Ctrl unnecessarily